# How to use Python to set up a tunnel matching an ssh command (for bastion)?

Tags: python, ssh

How would I set up a tunnel using Python code that could replace this command?

> ssh -N -L 3307:xxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@XX.XXX.XX.XX -i
>   ~/.ssh/bastion_key.pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sshtunnel`](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) library.

For example:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('XX.XXX.XX.XX', 22),
    ssh_username='ec2-user',
    ssh_pkey='~/.ssh/bastion_key.pem',
    remote_bind_address=('xxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 3307)
) as tunnel:
    # do stuff with tunnel
```